# How to fix the maximum size of an std::list?

Tags: c++

**How can i fix the maximum size of std::list ?**

Let's say that the maximum is 100, so my std::list will have a size that vary from 0 to 100.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The concept of a list that has (for instance) an error when you append to it beyond 100 is not something the standard list supports.

If standard container methods were virtual, you might use public inheritance and create a your own `bounded_list` which would do that.  You'd override every method which could potentially affect the size, and that would include the odd ones you've probably not heard of like [`emplace_back()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/emplace_back)...and put a little extra checking code.  But the methods aren't virtual, so really you wind up writing a new container; and it would have been a lot of work you don't want to do anyway.

Rather than trying to re-generalize a standard container with a "bounding" feature, usually in a design it's easier to define an abstract notion of your program's structures.  Speaking at the raw level of the container is hopefully not what most of your program is doing anyway--you don't `push_back` an employee, you do `Company.hireEmployee` (or whatever).  Those are better moments to do your checking; and you probably have more room to do semantically meaningful checks at the same time.  The idea is that it's easy to swap out one container for another--not that you've anchored your ship to a specially hooked container.

However, I do note Boost has a "bounded array", which is stack allocated.  It may or may not fit your purpose:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/bounded_array.htm

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to make sure your list is at most 100 elements, you could just make your own class, deriving from list, and override modifier functions like `push_back` and similar to do bound checking on the size.

Comment: `push_back` is not virtual, you can't override it.

Comment: Thanks @HostileFork. I don't know what I was thinking... :P